# grammar "The balls are of equal weight."

Tags: grammar

"The balls are of equal weight."
I think this sentence means "The balls are equal in weight."
Why do you say "of" here? What function and meaning does "of" have?
My guess is as follows
1)  He is of Polish descent (out of /from)
2)  The house is of his own design (out of /from)
3)  The trash smells of fish.(?)

Comment: "**equal weight**" is what these balls have. Consider this as an example like, "**this is of my concern**" or "**this is none of your business**"

Comment: They may also be *(composed)* of equal color and density.

Answer (score 1):

"**equal weight**" is what these balls have, it is theirs. Consider this as an example like, "**this is of my concern**" (the concern is mine) or "**this is none of your business**" (the business is not yours)